# CSS/HTML - Automatically adds padding to the top when I add a link to the images?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I link my images, it automatically brings the content down a little bit. I want it to be 3 in 1 row and aligned perfectly. When you look in the example, scroll down and the bottom 3 are the way I want it to look like.

*Where is my mistake?*

> See it yourself here: http://thequizmania.com/2100-2/#

**HTML**

```
<div id="pagewrap">
<br>
<p style="text-align: center">Quiz yourself. It's all about you!</p>


<a href="#">
    <section id="content">
                <img src="http://thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/>
        <h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
    </section>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <section id="middle">
                <img src="http://thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/>
        <h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
    </section>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <aside id="sidebar">
                <img src="http://thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/>
        <h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
    </aside>
</a>

<a href="#">    
    <section id="content">
                <img src="http://thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/>
        <h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
    </section>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <section id="middle">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QUuWywi.png" />
        <h3>What Color Is Your Personality?</h3>
    </section>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <section id="sidebar">
                <img src="http://thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/>
        <h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
    </section >
</a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#middle:hover {
background-color: #FFBFFF;
color: white;
} 

#sidebar:hover {
background-color: #FFBFFF;
color: white;
} 

#content:hover {
background-color: #FFBFFF;
color: white;
}
body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

#content {
    width: 265px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px;
border:thin #E4E4E4 solid;
transition:.3s;
}

#middle {
    width: 265px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
border:thin #E4E4E4 solid;

}

#sidebar {
    width: 265px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    float: left;
border:thin #E4E4E4 solid;

}
h2 {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #pagewrap {
        width: 94%;
    }
    #content {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }

    #middle {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 1%;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        float: right;
    }

    #sidebar {
        clear: both;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }


}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    #middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }

}


#content {
    background: white;
}
#middle { background: white; }
#sidebar {
    background: white;
}
#content, #middle, #sidebar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-right:50px;
text-align:center;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<p>...</p>` after each `anchor` that contains `image`? If you put the same `HTML` over there then it will display as expected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML in your question is different from the source code of your site. On your site, there are a bunch of `<p>` tags in between each section that have default margins that are throwing off the alignment of your images.

If you remove the `<p>` tags from the code on your site, the images will once again be properly aligned.

---

Here is a snippet of the source code from your site that shows all the extra `<p>` elements:

```
<p style="text-align: center">Quiz yourself. It&#8217;s all about you!</p>
<p><a href="#"></p>
<section id="content">
<img src="//thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/></p>
<h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
</section>
<p></a><br/>
<a href="#"></p>
<div id="middle">
<img src="//thequizmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01_quiz.png"/></p>
<h3>What Kind Of Karma Do You Have?</h3>
</p></div>
<p></a><br/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that there are a bunch of paragraph tags? I don't have any. I am using wordpress btw. Please, I need your guidance.

Comment: @Martin.html I've edited my answer to show you what your page's source code looks like. So it looks like your question is a Wordpress question, not really an HTML/CSS question. If you are entering your code in the Wordpress editor, you need to do it in "Text" mode, not "Visual" mode, otherwise Wordpress may try to format the code as a normal post and may insert garbage like extra `<p>` tags.

Comment: Brilliant! Never saw that coming. Thank you!